# Firebase quota exceeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'am trying to deploy my firebase functions (approximately 40 functions) but I'm getting the message error "HTTP Error: 429, Quota for Google Cloud Functions API exceeded for project XXX" and only some of the functions get updated/created. I know that limitation is because of the free plan that lets me deploy only 20 functions per 100 seconds!

So, how can I chose the functions I want to deploy without affecting the others?

Basically I'm looking for a way to deploy 20 functions then wait for 100 seconds and deploy the other 20 functions because letting only 20 function I want to deploy in my index.js file will delete the others from the server.

Thank you.

Comment: All functions are deployed at once, and whatever set of functions you deploy completely replaces any earlier set. There is no notion of partial, or individual, deployment of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Firebase CLI you can deploy specific functions like so:

`firebase deploy --only functions:function1,functions:function2,functions:function3...,functions:function20`

Comment: That didn't work! It shows me _No deploy targets found. Valid targets: database,storage,functions,hosting_

Comment: You should follow the guide on how to [setup the cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) for your project

Comment: It's not a setup problem, the `firebase deploy --only functions:function1` command doesn't exist!

Comment: It does in one of the latest version of the CLI https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v3.8.0 @stodi

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris, you 've saved my life.

Comment: Just a small correction. Using this way worked for me 
firebase deploy --only functions:function1,functions:function2,functions:function3...,functions:function20



It should be functions:function-name, functions:function-name